# Make a bucket sort

Tags: c++, sorting, bucket-sort

I'm trying to make a bucket sort but my program causes segmentation fault and i can't find out why. I use two extra functions which help me sort out the buckets i am using which are a swap function that changes two elements in a vector and then a bubble sort which uses the swap function. The vector given will always have 10 numbers and be between 0 and 99.

```
template <class T>
void Sorts<T>::swap(std::vector<T> &v, int i, int j) {
T aux = v[i];
v[i] = v[j];
v[j] = aux;
}

template <class T>
std::vector<T> Sorts<T>::bubbleSort(const std::vector<T> &source) {
std::vector<T> v(source);
for(int i  = v.size() -1; i > 0; i--){
    for(int j = 0;  j<i; j++){
        if(v[j] > v[j+1]){
            swap(v, j, j+1);
        }
    }
}
return v;
}

template <class T>
std::vector<T> Sorts<T>::bucketSort(const std::vector<T> &source) {
std::vector<T> v = source;
std::vector<T> b0, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9;

for(int i = 0; i < v.size()-1; i++){
    if(v[i] >= 0 && v[i] <= 9){
        b0.push_back(v[i]);
    } else if(v[i] >= 10 && v[i] <= 19){
        b1.push_back(v[i]);
    } else if(v[i] >= 20 && v[i] <= 29){
        b2.push_back(v[i]);
    } else if(v[i] >= 30 && v[i] <= 39){
        b3.push_back(v[i]);
    } else if(v[i] >= 40 && v[i] <= 49){
        b4.push_back(v[i]);
    } else if(v[i] >= 50 && v[i] <= 59){
        b5.push_back(v[i]);
    } else if(v[i] >= 60 && v[i] <= 69){
        b6.push_back(v[i]);
    } else if(v[i] >= 70 && v[i] <= 79){
        b7.push_back(v[i]);
    } else if(v[i] >= 80 && v[i] <= 89){
        b8.push_back(v[i]);
    } else if(v[i] >= 90 && v[i] <= 99){
        b9.push_back(v[i]);
    }
}

if(!b0.empty()){
    b0 = bubbleSort(b0);    
}
if(!b1.empty()){
    b1 = bubbleSort(b1);    
}
if(!b2.empty()){
    b2 = bubbleSort(b2);
}
if(!b3.empty()){
    b3 = bubbleSort(b3);
}
if(!b4.empty()){
    b4 = bubbleSort(b4);
}
if(!b5.empty()){
    b5 = bubbleSort(b5);
}
if(!b6.empty()){
    b6 = bubbleSort(b6);
}
if(!b7.empty()){
    b7 = bubbleSort(b7);
}
if(!b8.empty()){
    b8 = bubbleSort(b8);
}
if(!b9.empty()){
    b9 = bubbleSort(b9);
}

v.clear();

for(int i = 0; i < b0.size()-1; i++){
    v.push_back(b0[i]);
}
for(int i = 0; i < b1.size()-1; i++){
    v.push_back(b1[i]);
}
for(int i = 0; i < b2.size()-1; i++){
    v.push_back(b2[i]);
}
for(int i = 0; i < b3.size()-1; i++){
    v.push_back(b3[i]);
}
for(int i = 0; i < b4.size()-1; i++){
    v.push_back(b4[i]);
}
for(int i = 0; i < b5.size()-1; i++){
    v.push_back(b5[i]);
}
for(int i = 0; i < b6.size()-1; i++){
    v.push_back(b6[i]);
}
for(int i = 0; i < b7.size()-1; i++){
    v.push_back(b7[i]);
}
for(int i = 0; i < b8.size()-1; i++){
    v.push_back(b8[i]);
}
for(int i = 0; i < b9.size()-1; i++){
    v.push_back(b9[i]);
}


return v;
}
```

Comment: Try removing the template, I doubt you need it, you just need to specialize the vector to int like so `std::vector<int>`. Maybe add where the fault occurs, it might help isolate the problem.

Comment: Advice -- [You can reduce a lot of that redundant code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d86f8549cdf62bc).  You want to find the value that is within the range, so all you really need is to put the range limits in a sorted container, and use a binary search (`std::lower_bound`) to pinpoint which range to choose.  The code now becomes more scalable -- imagine if it were 20 or 30 ranges.

Comment: You forgot to add the calling code (main function...). Your current implementation will probably discard most of your input elements, which would explain a wrong result but not a segfault.

Comment: Your loops are too short. I suspect that the calling code is assuming that the result is the same size as the input,